# Is it possible to keep Mac App Store apps in the user application directory?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I have a MacBook Pro configured in the following way:

120GB SSD
    70GB OS X boot partition (10.8.2)
    50GB BootCamp partition
750GB WD HDD
    Essentially all used as my Home folder

Is it possible to keep some of the larger (less frequently used) application in my ~/Applications folder while still allowing the MAS purchased apps to receive updates? A simple alias will certainly not do the trick, but is there a way to create a symlink that will allow the linked file to receive the upgrade?

I'd like to remove some of the larger, less frequently used applications from the (space-limited) SSD… This makes me appreciated the elegance required in creating the FusionDrive framework!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if there is such a possibility to have this as a default behavior but you could simply move the application to your user application directory or anywhere else.

Finder by default creates an alias when you drag an application out of the `/Applications` folder. However, if you hold down the "Command" key while dragging your applications, they will move to wherever you drag them.

If you want to go a geekier route, you can also use Terminal and execute this command:

```
sudo mv /Applications/your-application.app ~/Applications/
```

After promting for your login password everything is fine. Be sure to be administrator of your system.

This certainly works for me. I can use the application as usual and it receives all updates via the Mac App Store.

Comment: We'll find out when some of those apps get updates, but all apps seem happy at the moment! Thanks for the input.

Comment: I routinely move MAS apps from /Applications to ~/Applications.  They still receive updates.  As bispymusic mentions you have to hold down the Command key to move them and authenticate.